# Not able to fetch the data from external JSON

Tags: jquery, html, json

I would like to display the number of people with hazel eyes color from the External JS file..

and also

The top 10 most common surnames with their totals.

this is for windows/linus server I need to fetch the data..

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d020135436357a4732e",
    "balance": "1,171.56",
    "age": 46,
    "eyeColor": "hazel",
    "name": {
      "first": "Colon",
      "last": "Key"
    },
    "company": "Orbaxter",
    "email": "colonkey@orbaxter.com",
    "phone": "+1 (938) 402-3422",
    "address": "706 Tennis Court, Kimmell, Indiana, 4057",
    "registered": "2014-12-24T10:31:42 -00:00",
    "latitude": 22.250647,
    "longitude": -67.325278
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d027f167186f52e2e6c",
    "balance": "1,383.36",
    "age": 23,
    "eyeColor": "hazel",
    "name": {
      "first": "Byrd",
      "last": "Walls"
    },
    "company": "Bizmatic",
    "email": "byrdwalls@bizmatic.com",
    "phone": "+1 (817) 569-3406",
    "address": "187 Lewis Avenue, Lutsen, Oregon, 7387",
    "registered": "2017-06-19T09:24:42 -01:00",
    "latitude": -60.642235,
    "longitude": -62.947158
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d023f1f434dcb1ea87d",
    "balance": "2,338.81",
    "age": 21,
    "eyeColor": "grey",
    "name": {
      "first": "Sondra",
      "last": "Booker"
    },
    "company": "Aquazure",
    "email": "sondrabooker@aquazure.com",
    "phone": "+1 (861) 495-3729",
    "address": "633 Billings Place, Jacumba, Louisiana, 1488",
    "registered": "2017-12-11T08:53:27 -00:00",
    "latitude": 18.681413,
    "longitude": 93.058578
  }
]
```

I need to get:

1. The number of people with green eyes
2. The top 10 most common surnames with their totals
3. The details of the person who lives closest to the Eiffel Tower
4. The average age of everyone with blue eyes

Comment: What have your tried?

Comment: Is the problem that you can't get the JSON to return, or that you're unable to filter the returned JSON?

Comment: I would like to display or in alert The number of people with grey eyes

Comment: Please give me a solution using jquery... I tried below code..
$.getJSON('fakepeople.json', function (data) {
  //console.log(val.eyeColor );
  var items = [];
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val.eyeColor + "</li>" );
    });
    $( "<ul/>", {
        "class": "my-new-list",
        html: items.join( "" )
    }).appendTo( "body" );

});